Is it possible to add a PostgreSQL hot standby using pg_createcluster to a primary created with initdb?
Hi we are using PostgreSQL 16 on Ubuntu 22 LTS and have built a cluster using initdb.  I'm wondering if it's possible to rebuild a standby using pg_createcluster instead to take advantage of various admin tools and join it to the cluster so that we can eventually failover (we use repmgr), and then remove the old nodes and rebuild them using pg_createcluster as well.
As I understand it pg_createcluster is essentially a wrapper around initdb.  Unfortunately being in production, simply rebuilding the entire cluster is a no-go, so our choice is to either live with it having been built using initdb, or add/remove nodes until the entire cluster is rebuilt with pg_createcluster.

pg_createcluster is a script around initdb.  initdb creates a new database cluster, but that is not what you need for streaming replication: you need a copy of the primary cluster. So you need pg_basebackup or some other file system backup technique to create the standby as copy of the primary.

So just to be clear, I can not get the tools around pg_createcluster added once a cluster has been built via initdb, even if trying to add it via new standby?

You are not clear :^( The only way you can get pg_createcluster is by installing the PostgreSQL packages on a Debian or Ubuntu machine. That has nothing to do with a standby.

So once I have done that on an instance, can I use that instance to be added in as a hot standby to another instance that was created via initdb that is still on Ubuntu?  I know pg_basebackup creates a back up and restores it over top existing dbs and that’s okay.  I just want to be able to still use tools like pg_lscluster afterwards, and eventually replace all instances to have that by pulling them out and rebuilding the binaries.

I think I get you. Yes, that is what I do on Debian systems: I create a cluster with pg_createcluster, then I remove the data directory and replace it with pg_basebackup. You have to transfer the configuration manually.

Thank you, that’s exactly what I was looking for.
